# Any tool to check circular dependency in a Delphi project

Tags: delphi

It's said that circular dependencies in a Delphi project can significantly slow down the compile time, is there any tool can check circular dependencies for a Delphi project? Thanks!

EDIT:
The following ICARUS report summary shows it took 32 seconds for a full compilation of 0.8M LOC (Thanks to Alan for the suggestion), I'm wondering if there is still any room to improve ;)

Analyzed by:            ICARUS - Uses List Analyzer for Delphi version 3.3.2.0
Parse speed:            801722 lines in 32.50 seconds (24671 lines/sec)

Comment: Circular dependencies are not possible in Delphi. Try creating two units that reference each other in the interface section. You will get an error.

Comment: @The_Fox: "Delphi: Optimizing extremely long compile times" at http://www.delphifeeds.com/go/s/71351 : "2. Avoid large circular dependency groups", and "Complex cyclic unit relations can considerably increase compilation times up to hours" on http://www.modelmakertools.com/articles/unit-dependencies.html

Comment: @mjustin: Hours? Really? I work on some pretty large and complex projects (1M LOC and counting), and have yet to see compile times of which I can't count the minutes on the fingers of one hand... What in ... are they doing to get up to hours? Stunned....

Comment: @Marjan: with the right hardware (Pentium 5?) this should be possible :)

Comment: @mjustin: :) yes, with the right hardware anything is possible, though I think even my poor old Pentium II 233MHz with 96 MB of memory running Win2K, wouldn't get up to even a single hour on our projects. Anyway... getting them modelmaker dependency analyzer should help, though I'd recommend the full modelmaker to help in refactoring those codebases! :D

Comment: @mjustin: I was talking about circular references, classA refers to classB and classB refers to classA. But you are right, you can still create dependencies where unit A uses unit B and vice versa. About the links: the first link links to another page where compiletime went from 3,3 minutes to 11 seconds, but not because of removing dependencies but because of Delphi Speedup. The second link, hours to compile, does anyone know of such a Delphi project? Smells more like marketing mumbo jumbo and not something an average developer should be afraid of.

Comment: Circular references are not the only possible reason for long compilation times - see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2776932/adding-files-to-the-dpr-file-vs-project-paths-in-delphi-2010/2777819#2777819 which says "Having all your units explicitly in the dpr immensely improves compilation time, code completion, error insight and general navigation."

Comment: @the_fox: It's possible, unitA references unitB in the interface section, and unitB references unitA in the implementation section.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Gerrit Beuze from ModelMaker Tools provides the free [Unit Dependency Analyzer](http://www.modelmakertools.com/articles/unit-dependencies.html).

Comment: There is a free version of it, good! Graphical presentation is a pleasure to view

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend the freeware [Peganza Icarus](http://www.peganza.com/products_icarus.htm), it generates a uses report and recommends optimizations.

Comment: Thanks! It does not show cyclic references though.