# File not found xxxxx.dcu

Tags: delphi, compiler-errors, delphi-2007

I'm trying to locate which unit in my app uses a specific .dcu . As i don't know which unit is, i've renamed the dcu to generate an exception in compiler-time :

[DCC Error] F1026 - File not found 'IdThread.dcu'

Is there a way to locate in my project the unit using this file ? I know it's an Indy related unit, but in my project i don't have ANY Indy components !

Comment: What happens when you search for that text?

Comment: idThread not used by you, but it can be used by any other class/library which you uses in the project.

Comment: why not just searching in the sources ? Dephi - menu - edit - find in files
or any GREP utility
or any text-finding utility like Total Commander 

just find the DCY filename in your sources

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3076048/ and see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3573249

Comment: Delphi 2007 in this case. I tried to search inside project using Find in files and GREP, none was was found.

Comment: Somewhere in your uses clause is an indy file.  They start with 'id'.  You'll have to find it and remove the reference.

Answer (score 0):

As a last resort, you can use a grep-like tool to search within the DCUs themselves: e.g. Using the build in windows findstr command:

```
findstr /ism "\<idthread\>" *.dcu

ObscureUnit.dcu
IdScheduler.dcu
```

will list any DCUs with a reference to IdThread. 
You may need to check in the library path as well as a unit you only have in compiled format may have a reference.

Of course, IdThread may be used in a unit that is used by another unit that your project uses. You may need to perform this operation recursively.

**NOTE:** This may not work on a Unicode version of Delphi, as findstr doesn't support Unicode, and I'm not sure if the reference in the dcu uses Unicode. If it does, use a Unicode enabled version of grep, or use the SysInternals `Strings` utility to extract the "readable" text from the dcu files.