# Pros and cons of explicitly adding your unit names to Delphi's project source

Tags: delphi

I've been using Delphi for years and years and each of my projects is compiled from source into the exe - no packages etc. If 'MyUnitA.pas' is used anywhere, it is simply declared in the interface or implementation section of another unit that requires it. This all works fine everywhere and means that in my project source (dpr) there are only frame definitions (which seem to be needed there else they dont show up in the frame list) and the 'odd' definition of a unit that must be called very early eg madExcept, FastMM etc.

I notice that XE baulks a bit sometimes at resolving stuff in the dpr until you actually compile it. In addition, when working with packages its a warning if stuff has to be implicitly pulled in without having been explicitly added to the package. This got me wondering whether we should be diligently adding ALL of our used units to our dpr (like the package definition) or right-click project and 'Add to project'. What do you do?

Answer (score 5):

I personally have my search path blank and include all units in my .dpr files. The main advantages of this as I see it:

- I know precisely which files are included in my project.
- View Units (Ctrl+F12), View Forms (Shift+F12) offer all units and forms in the project.

I don't really see any significant disadvantages to this approach. Yes you have to add files to the .dpr file when you include a new 3rd party component, but in my experience that doesn't happen all that often for it to be a big burden.

Comment: And you can use a {$I sadasdda} declaration for common stuf. Do you use relative paths?

Comment: I do indeed use relative paths. That's essential really.

Comment: @BrianFrost The include is a nice idea. But the IDE strips it out when rebuilding the uses clause if you add/remove files. (This might depend on which version of the IDE you're using.)

Comment: @Craig I'm not talking about a $INCLUDE at all. I add all the units to the project. A $INCLUDE is no use.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Did you change your name? I'm pretty sure you're not Brian Frost. He **did** suggest using {$I}.

Comment: Isn't a waste of time to compile all that code into one DPR file? If the code is split into libraries, you could take advantage of precompiled DCUs.

Comment: @IceCold where is the time wasted? Unless you have a huge code base compilation is generally quick. And usually you only need to recompile a few units, the ones you changed since the last compilation.

Comment: My program is 0.46 mill SLOC. It builds in 2.6 seconds because all business logic and components are separated in libraries (I also don't use Spring or something like it). So, I basically I only compile the GUI. My setup is similar to the one described by Cosmin P. However, I have worked in projects (multiple) where 1 mill SLOC is pulled directly into one DPR. In this case, the time is way over one minute. If code would be split in libraries, then the time would be smaller.

Comment: @IceCold If you've not changed the library code, then it won't be recompiled when you make the project. The compiler will only compile units that have been modified since the last time they were compiled. So yes the first build from scratch will take longer but then my approach performs the same as yours. And dependencies are simpler to handle.

Answer (score 4):

I am with David on this one. We/I do exactly the same.

Dependency control is the main benefit. Explicitness in unit use has big advantages. I am never in doubt where the source for a project is coming from.

Another benefit is that we as a team we are never dependent upon search paths in the IDE. All our machines have empty search paths, only items in the debug search path if we are working on getting a control to do our bidding. We only add controls to our IDE when working on the GUI (which is a large in itself, but actually a small part of our software and we use mainly controls that ship with Delphi). And I often de-install them afterwards. Big advantage: when I need to work on a very old version, I can simply pull it from Perforce and build it with the right Delphi compiler. Everything else is taken care of in the dproj (or dof as we can still compile the versions that were based on D5).

Not relying on search paths in the IDE also means our build server doesn't need to be configured with any search paths. We have a utility that  keeps the dproj's in line with the configured third party library versions for a version of our software. And we have a utility that creates a cfg file from the dproj/dof. This way, we can build each and every version of our software that is still in use anywhere in the world, regardless of the compiler and third party component versions it needs. And we can do it without changing a single thing in the build server's setup. In fact we build all "active" releases every night if a change was committed to its Perforce branch and don't even think about it.

Comment: Why would you ever doubt about the location of your source code? In how many places has your code been duplicated?

Comment: Duplication isn't the problem. Different versions of libraries (even your own) in use in different projects is (software suite with 30+ projects). Using the search path doesn't allow for that. Plus: upgrading a library to a different version can break all manner of things, so you want full, explicit control over what version is used in each project.

Comment: For 3rd party libraries, I personally have one library version. All programs MUST use that single version. Most of those 3rd party libs (Drag&Drop, Gr32, etc) are doing a great job in remaining backwards compatible.         For my personal libraries, when I upgrade one, all programs that use that library are also upgraded to support it (but only if the upgrade breaks something - which rarely happens).

Comment: @IceCold: Untenable rule when dealing with the applications I worked on at the time. Every library update, even the 'simple' ones, was a huge risk for introducing subtle, hard-to-find bugs in our proprietary code that pushed 32 bit computers far beyond their memory limits.

Comment: I agree with you here. I drastically reduced the number of 3rd party libs over the years.

Answer (score 4):

(Test made on Delphi Xe3 Enterprise)
1 000 000 lines project, 1000 classes, 300 units

- **First approach :**

  - Search path contains only vcl sources paths
  - All files declared in project file with pathnames (around 300 files)
  - I had lots of troubles :

    - The Delphi Ide was hanging permanently, with "100% cpu" in the task manager
    - Lots of underlined code , mostly "identifiers not found"
    - Ctrl+Enter on symbols was not working most of the time
    - Project file very hard to edit, had to wait few seconds after each key stroke
- **Second approach :**

  - All search paths in project options (~50 paths)
  - All files declared in project file without any pathnames (around 300 files)
  - Results :

    - No more hangings in Delphi Ide
    - No more underlined identifiers in code
    - Project file much more responsive
    - Faster compile time (~ 10-15%)
    - My mother in law left the house
  - Cons :

    - "Find in files" for project file, unusable, I had to use the "Search in directories"
      options. But it will also scan files not from my project.
      For me it's not a big deal

Comment: +1 for getting rid of your mother in law! ;)

Comment: Search path contains only "vcl" sources paths. By VCL you mean Embarcadero VCL? That's not good!

Answer (score 3):

Cons of adding unit names to each and every project:

- Starting a new project requires a lot of "boiler-plate". This is a problem for short-lived projects.
- Not all projects are under my control. I *can* control my co-worker's search path, because it's 1 thing that needs to be changed, but I can't control each and every project, because that's no longer 1 thing. We work on very few very large projects, but we often have lots of tiny small utility or helper projects.
- Makes refactoring difficult. If we have 20 projects using unit A, and we make unit A dependent on unit B, we'll need to add unit B to all 20 projects. If those 20 projects are managed by 5 different programmers in the company, things start looking ugly. If on the other hand all 20 projects by 5 programmers can find unit B through the search path, things are easy.
- Makes it easy to have multiple version of the same unit, because the given unit got copied when a project was cloned. In my book that's a Bad Thing.

I personally keep all "library" units, including 3rd party packages into one big folder that's under version control. We call this folder the "Work Environment" and we have a in-house tool that "activates" the environment (ie: it corrects the search path for the IDE, installs packages, copies stuff to System folder, adds entries to the Registry, even creates some Start Menu shortcuts). This works *very* well for me.

Comment: "I personally keep all "library" units, including 3rd party packages into one big folder that's under version control."  Doesn't this make it impossible to maintain different versions of the same project?

Comment: No, it just makes it a little bit more inconvenient: I can only have one version of the environment active at a time, so I'd need to take turns working on different versions of the project (one at a time) or install on multiple virtual machines. Since my "work environment" is practically self-installing, I can commission a new VM in less then 30 minutes.

Comment: It's hard to see how your solution is better than mine in that regard. I'll take my 0 minutes over your 30 minutes any day!

Comment: I don't think there's a generally "better" solution. I'll take my 30 minutes because it's not something I do every day, but I do change and refactor library code every day. And I really, really enjoy the ability to "push" those changes to my colleagues.

Comment: What do you mean by *I really, really enjoy the ability to "push" those changes to my colleagues*? You don't need to use search paths to do that.

Comment: Yes I do, if I'm not working on the same projects my colleagues are working on. For example I recently built "merged cells" functionality into our in-house Grid. Of course everyone wants those changes. If everyone had the Grid in a subdirectory of one's project, they'd need to manually patch them all.

Comment: We use revision control to do that. What if the changes were wanted in some projects but not others. Then you'd be stuck.

Comment: We can't use revision control for that because we're using Mercurial, and it doesn't have what Subversion calls `svn:external`. I make my changes backwards-compatible and I assure you *all* projects want the changes, I wouldn't have it any other way (because I've been burnt by having multiple current versions of the same thing, don't want it any more).

Comment: Sounds like a big weakness in the revision control system. Even svn:external is a bit flaky. In my setting I would not be able to force changes in shared modules onto other projects because of the issues of maintaining and developing different versions of the same project. And as for always maintaining backwards compatibility, sometimes I make changes that change functionality even if the interface is the same.

Comment: Salutări @CosminPrund. I use a similar setup. Works great :)

Answer (score 2):

The way I do it:

- Relative library paths in the project options. This keeps compiling quick because the IDE doesn't have to search through every directory for even the smallest app. Also, this means I can check out my code out anywhere and it will compile.
- Only include the main forms and units in my project file. Basically, my glue code (which are usually my forms) ends up in the project file. This keeps my unit dependencies under control, and helps when I am refactoring.
- In my DUnit suite, the testing classes are my glue code and as such are the only ones in my project file.

Relative paths are essential for properly managing your source code. As I said, you can check your code out anywhere and it will still compile. I often check out my code in my temp directory to do a code spike, or to check out an old version to compile and run to compare things. It literally takes me about 2 minutes to get a new build environment going.

My continuous integration server runs as a service on my machine, and checks out and builds to a different directory, and does not interfere with my development environment. This would be impossible with absolute paths.

I end up doing a lot of CTRL-Clicking on identifiers in code to navigate around (when code insight is working, which is only about half the time), or CTRL-Entering on unit names...

Something I learnt many years ago is that you can type a unit name anywhere in your code and hit CTRL-Enter and it will open the unit. Obviously you need to delete what you've typed eventually, but it is quick!

If you want the units to appear in your ALT-F11 "use units" dialog, use [DDevExtensions](http://andy.jgknet.de/blog/ide-tools/ddevextensions/), which replaces the dialog with a new one that includes all the units in your search path, not just the ones in your project. An awesome tool just for that feature alone.

(Note: I have had problems with DDevExtensions "use units" with relative library paths in large projects. It's still worth trying though)

(Note 2: This seems to be fixed with 2.4.1. Oh, and I got the name wrong, I had IDE Fix Pack, but it is actually DDevExtensions)

N@

Comment: "My continuous integration server runs as a service on my machine" - May I ask what you use Nat?

Comment: @brian-frost I use CruiseControl.net with Nant. I also have a suite of Nant tasks I have written for the Delphi command line compilers (dcc32, rc32), oh and an XMLTestRunner for DUnit so all the unit testing bits work nicely. I suppose I should make the Nant tasks available for community at large...

Answer (score 1):

The biggest disadvantage I found in adding files to the .dpr and .dproj it is it will ensure you will get "conflicts" from many VCS, if you add line A while your coworkers adds line B in the same place, and you will get conflicts in both files. They are easy to solve in the .dpr, more confusing in the .dproj, which is usually not very well formatted.
There's an issue here that originally Delphi used only the .dpr to list the files, then started to use both files, while IMHO now the use clause of the .dpr should only be used as in any other source file, while the list of files used in the project should be mantained in the .dproj only (the IDE project management needs really to be improved, instead of becoming even more messy...).
For this reason I have 1) a library folder for 3rd party standard library (an environment variable sets is root path, allowing different projects to use different ones) 2) a project library path with files not shared with other projects 3) Only the relevant files are added to the project source, mostly forms/datamodules.

Answer (score 1):

Con: Issue 77687 in Quality Central:

[Editing in the .dpr source gets slower with more units in the project](http://qc.embarcadero.com/wc/qcmain.aspx?d=77687)

> Editing in the .dpr source can be very
>   slow even with all Code Insight
>   options disabled. It get slower the
>   more units the project has (the
>   content of the units doesn't matter).

Answer (score 1):

I use relative searchpaths and only put units related to visual inheritance in dpr. The main reason to keep the project relative is so that it can be build in any location. (and you can quickly checkout something old without messing with paths or substs). For me that is a key feature, and I'm prepared to live with other minor problems to achieve that.

Since I not only use unit files, but also .inc files (for defines and crosscompiler compatibility) I need search paths anyway.

With this setup. I only have one problem, namely that under some circumstances when changing project the working directory gets stuck. And all (relative + project dir) paths are relative to the working directory, not the project.  That causes trouble with similar unit names in the project directory, or when switching between projects with similarly set up relative paths and I can't imagine it being any different with David's setup

So I mostly made a habit of closing a project before opening a new one and File->open and loading any file from the "real" project fixes this in case it gets messed up.

I never really got bitten by duplicate unit problems. Apparently my basic file hygiene is enough for that. (but if you really are scared, a simple script could perform a check), so that is no reason for me to micromanage the .dpr

Answer (score 0):

Experience has taught me that David's way works well for all home grown code, because by including everything in your project, you always have all your source readily available and viewable, and if there's a problem you can get immediately to the spot.

I learned this years ago (although sometimes I ignore it due to laziness...) from working on a large project I inherited that didn't follow this practice - I spent weeks foraging around directories and network shares in search of 'used' units that I needed to see the source for.

But I don't include units from packages/components etc in the project - gets too unwieldly in sheer size, and you also get all kinds of 'alien' units in there that disrupt the flow of your project views, etc. Also - I'd rather not see the warnings that are sometimes left in those packages... LOL

The main disadvantage I've found is that in team development, unless you **strictly enforce** a consistent directory structure for all code across the whole team, the build is likely to get broken quite often.

HTH